# Canvas pre rendering?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Is there any point in pre-rendering images on canvas?

An example,

```
var img; // Img object

var pre = document.createElement("canvas");
pre.width = img.width;
pre.height = img.height;
var precon = pre.getContext("2d");

precon.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

for(var i =0; i < 10000; ++i) {
    ctx.drawImage(pre, Math.random() * canvas.width, Math.random() * canvas.height);
}
```

I don't see the point as you are still calling `context.drawImage` no matter what you do, unless the canvas api is faster drawing an image from a canvas object rather than image object?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Firstly, I must say that your example is not suitable to highlight the need and benefits of canvas pre-rendering.

I'll give you a better example were you need to draw multiple times something that requires heavy computation on a canvas.

Let's say you have this `draw` function :

```
function complexDraw(ctx){
    ctx.drawImage(img, width, height);
    // heavy computation goes here
    // some transforms maybe
    ctx.ctx.setTransform(-1, 0, 0, 1, 200, 200);   
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(100, 100, 255, 0.5)";   
    ctx.fillRect(50, 50, 100, 100); 
    //maybe draw another img/video/canvas
    ctx.drawImage(anotherImg, width, height);
    // ...
}
function draw(){
    complexDraw(ctx);
}
```

Now let's say you want to show the current time on the canvas too. That means that we're going to add this at the bottom of our `draw` function :

```
function drawTime(ctx){
    ctx.fillText(new Date().getTime(), 10, 50); 
}
```

And now our draw function looks like this :

```
function draw(){
    complexDraw(ctx);
    drawTime(ctx);
}
```

Since you want to always show the current time, you need to call the `draw` function every second :

```
setInterval(draw, 1000);
```

This actually means that every second you are doing some heavy computation just to update a silly little text.

If only there could be a way to split the `draw` function and compute only the things that  need computing (the ones that change)... but there is: say hello to canvas pre-rendering!

The key idea is to draw the part that doesn't change (and doesn't need to be re-computed) on a separate canvas - let's call it `cacheCanvas` - and just copy it's content on our app's canvas whenever we want to redraw stuff :

```
// suppose we have a `clone` function
var cacheCanvas = clone(canvas),
    cacheCtx = cacheCanvas.getContext('2d');

// let's draw our complex stuff on the cacheCanvas
complexDraw(cacheCtx);

// modify our main `draw` function to copy the result of the `complexDraw`
// function, not to call it
function draw(){
    ctx.drawImage(cacheCanvas, width, height);
    drawTime();
}
```

And now we're basically redrawing the whole canvas each second, but we're not re-computing all the heavy work in `complexDraw`.

I just want to note that most of the canvas based games can't run at 60fps (redraw **60 times per second**) without doing some performance boost with **pre rendering** or another technique called **canvas layering** (which is also worth looking into).

Comment: Yes I have implemented layering and find it mush easier to create things like parallax scrolling etc, thanks for this, it was a brilliant insight!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! In a canvas game I'm making, I render a few hundred rects every frame to texturize my landscape. It wasn't laggy on my rig, but this would help me make it faster on slower computers.

Comment: How is this going to animate your canvas ?

your cache canvas is only getting drawn once, (complexDraw(cacheCtx);)
isnt this going to draw the first image over and over ?

Comment: It's just an example.I haven't implemented all the functionality in this answer :). Suppose that every minute you need to draw complex stuff (via the `complexDraw` function). You will compute the complex logic only once per miunte and cache the result in the cache canvas. This way, even if you have 60 FPS, you will only execute the heavy logic once per miunte, not for every frame (`draw` call).

Comment: ok thanks, so if i understand correctly, lets say you need to calculate the complexDraw every frames. It is going to be faster if you draw the image previously calculated, then calculate the complexDraw for the next frame ?

Comment: @MartinLarocque Nope, if you need to call `complexDraw` on every `draw` function, then it won't add any performance improvement.

Comment: @gion_13 ok so just to be clear, if you have a complexDraw to do every frame, theres no way to pre render it ?

Comment: @MartinLarocque yes, it’s the same principle as in any other caching situation: you should cache the result of a complex computation if you can re-use that result later without having to go through the logic again. If you need to recalculate and redraw something on every frame, prerendering it won’t have any positive impact on performance.